# Handling multiple touches on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am currently developing an app where I have kind of a main view with lots of subviews. Now I have two specific subviews and I want only one of them to be "touchable" at once. So both should be able to response to a touch event but it should not be able that both respond simultaneously. Since I have other subview which should be able to touch at the same time I cannot use the multitouch or exclusiveTouch property.
Any ideas on this? Maybe I could kind of group both view to a single-touch area.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Stick a read-write property, let's call it `viewBeingTouched`, in your app delegate or some other singleton. Make sure you use `@property` **without** `nonatomic`.

Make your two views instances of a class that overrides the `UIResponder` methods thusly:

1. In touchesBegan, check the value of `viewBeingTouched`. If it's `nil`, set it to `self` and call the super's implementation. Otherwise, do nothing.
2. In touchesEnded, check the value of `viewBeingTouched`. If it's `self`, set it to nil.

Get it? The first view to get a touch grabs the property and prevents the other from registering it.

Comment: Thx, I think I got it. I will try it out today in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

Put logic in their parent that (temporarily) disables the one that didn't get the touch (userInteractionEnabled = NO).

Of course, someone could still put a finger down on each of them simultaneously. You could figure which view is closest to the center of the touches.

Comment: I did disable one view with userInteractionEnabled when the other received a touchesBegan event but as you said it is still possible to press them both simultaneously.
I also tried sending a touchesEnded event to the view which got touched secondly but this didn't work at all.

Comment: Although they will be pressed simultaneously, they cannot both be sent touchesBegan simultaneously, which is why Lawrence's suggestion should work.